# Messages are not getting acknowledged in cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to use google pubsub with cloud functions all of my things worked greatly but my messages are not being ackowledged

I have done these things:

1) Created a topic

2) Created a function

3) set trigger of function as google cloud pubsub

4) select topic for pubsub

5) set node version as 8

This is my default cloud function:

```
/**
 * Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event Event payload.
 * @param {!Object} context Metadata for the event.
 */
exports.helloPubSub = (event, context) => {
  const pubsubMessage = event.data;
  console.log(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage, 'base64').toString());
};
```

It will create 2 subscriptions for this topic one is pull and other to push

My cloud function is getting called but my messages are not getting acknowledged.

According to [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#functions-deploy-command-node8)

> Note: Cloud Functions acks the message internally upon successful function execution. For information on how to handle failures using retries, see Retrying Background Functions.

So functions should acknowledge automatically bit it is not working.

what is problem in this flow. what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to determine that your messages are not being acknowledged? Also, from what I can see running examples, cloud functions only creates a single push subscription, it does not create any pull subscription.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Ah, I found that you do not need to make the subscription.  When deploying the cloud function and pointing it at a topic, the subscription is automatically created.  Any secondary subscription you create has no consumers thus messages will not be acknowledged.  Also, if your cloud function is failing it's messages may not be acknowledged.

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO Brillant ! I did waste 2 hours on this without any doc from Google !

Comment: you should add this as an answer! @ProGirlXOXO saved me hours

Comment: Thx @FabianBosler. Done, hope it helps others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly create the subscription for a pubsub cloud function.

When deploying the cloud function and pointing it at a topic, the subscription is automatically created.

1. Create `your-topic`:

   `gcloud pubsub topics create your-topic`
2. Deploy function pointing at `your-topic` (this automatically creates a subscription):

   `gcloud functions deploy your-function --region=us-central1 --trigger-topic=your-topic --runtime=python37 --entry-point=main`

Run deploy command from the folder with your cloudfunction code. You can change the `runtime` and `entry-point` to match your use case.

Any secondary subscription you create has no consumers thus messages will not be acknowledged. Also, if your cloud function is failing it's messages may not be acknowledged.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try writing, deploying, and triggering a Background Cloud Function with a Cloud Pub/Sub trigger then the following documentation page is better.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub

I think you needs to trigger the function.

```
gcloud pubsub topics publish YOUR_TOPIC_NAME --message YOUR_MESSAGE
```